# react native run-ios command takes time like 8~10 mins. is it normal?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and tried

'run-ios' command to run app on ios.

It took about 8~10 mins average to build.

I am wondering is it normal behavior of react-native.

I tried 'run-android' command on another lab-top and

result seems same :( So I am about to think this might be

normal symthom...

how much time you guys took to build react-native apps???

expo cli with expo start seems fast but react native run-ios

seems very very very very VERY slow...

Do I really have to wait 8~10 mins to build?

I am wondering am I suffering alone.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your app size, but first install always very long( build in xcode much faster).I recommend you don't use react-native run-ios, use debug tools,it will be faster. For example vscode has very simple debugger,but if you want run application at a time, you can use xcode build

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, it was because of my slow wifi the build was slow.
test your build with a faster internet and see what happens.